# I need clarifications on these terms exception and directives @Try, @finally, @throw

Tags: objective-c

1. What is the general reason an exception occur? When an exception appears, does the program terminate immediately or keep running?
2. I'm guessing @try is the program message I'm testing. Is that right?
3. After @catch either log an error message, clean up, etc, what does the @finally block do? The book I'm reading says that @finally determines whether or not a statement in an @try throws an exception. But isn't that an unnecessary step because with or without it, we could tell whether there was an exception based on the program terminating abruptly?
4. What's the throw directive? The books says it enables you to throw your own exception. But I find that really confusing. Does that mean I could somehow create an exception and test it out?

I would really appreciate it if you could answer at least one of the questions for me. 
Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you do a literature search on "exceptions".  If nothing else, study the Java exception mechanism, since it's a fairly good, clean implementation.  Maybe even dig out some articles on the old Ada exception mechanism.  Then you can begin to understand the Objective-C scheme.  Trying to understand it by itself will drive you crazy (and leave you with some serious misconceptions besides).

Comment: (Among other things, it's important to understand exceptions in the context of procedure calls and `{}` blocks.  If you simply regard it as a fancy "goto" mechanism then you seriously miss the point.)

Comment: Also note that **exceptions should not be used to handle recoverable errors in programs built for iOS and OS X**.

Comment: @HotLicks I know where you're coming from, but pointing someone to Ada when they're trying to learn about Objective-C probably isn't going to help. Wikipedia or your answer below are much better!

Comment: The reason for bringing up Ada is that it would drag along a lot of the rationale of the Ada exception model (which is what we're essentially talking about here).  Later work is most often just a description of language features, with no rationale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exceptions provide a mechanism for handling errors and other unusual events outside the normal flow of execution. They allow the programmer to write cleaner code by eliminating the need to constantly check for and handle errors. Instead, when an error happens, the code can "throw" an exception object, and execution will stop at that point and resume at the first "catch" block that can handle the exception. I could explain further, but I'm sure you'll get a better explanation of exceptions in general by reading the relevant Wikipedia page.

So, with that in mind, the directives you mention allow for exceptions in Objective-C:

- **@try:** Code in a try block may throw an exception. Try blocks are usually followed by catch blocks which can catch whatever exceptions might be thrown by the code in the try block, but it's also possible that a given exception needs to be handled at a higher level. In that case, the relevant catch block may be somewhere higher up, like in the method that called the method with the try block, or the one above that. (Those methods would also have try blocks that would have called the current method.)
- **@catch:** Catch blocks contain code for handling a given exception and hopefully recovering from the exceptional condition.
- **@finally:** The finally block contains code that performs any needed cleanup for the try block. For example, if the try block allocated some resources, the finally block could deallocate those resources before allowing the exception to move up to the next catch handler.
- **@throw:** This is a directive that's used to "throw" an exception. Execution of the try block stops at the point where an exception is thrown, and the exception will be handled (or not) by a catch block. (Unhandled exceptions generally cause the program to terminate.)

Now, with all that said, you should usually **avoid exceptions in Objective-C**. I know it seems strange to have this great feature built into the language and then not be able to use it, but Objective-C programs are almost always written using the Cocoa or Cocoa Touch frameworks, and those frameworks don't expect to have exceptions thrown across framework calls.

> What is the general reason an exception occur? When an exception
>   appears, does the program terminate immediately or keep running?

You throw an exception when something unexpected happened that prevents your code from continuing. For example, trying to access the n+1th element in an array with only n items throws an exception. In Cocoa or Cocoa Touch programs, exceptions are terminal. In other languages and frameworks, though, exceptions may be handled to allow the program to continue running.

> After @catch either log an error message, clean up, etc, what does the
>   @finally block do?

A finally block runs whether or not an exception is thrown, so you don't need to have cleanup code in both your try block and your catch block. Also, catch blocks often catch exceptions that were thrown at a lower level, so they may not be able to clean up.

> What's the throw directive? The books says it enables you to throw your own exception.

`@throw;` (without a parameter) in a catch block re-throws the same exception that the catch block was handling, so that it can be dealt with at a higher level.

It sounds like you're probably reading *Programming in Objective-C* by Steven Kochan. If I remember correctly, Kochan tries to teach you Objective-C divorced from Cocoa and Cocoa Touch. That might make sense at some level, but this is one case where it'll probably confuse you more than is necessary, especially if you're trying to learn the language so that you can use one or both of those frameworks. Given [Apple's advice against using exceptions in your code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Exceptions.html), it's probably safe to stop reading and move on to the next chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Understand that you have a block of code -- between `{}` characters -- that may produce a runtime error message.  In many systems that runtime error message is either sent to some log and ignored, or it causes the application to terminate abruptly.

With exceptions, the code that detects the error creates an exception object and "throws" it with a `throw` statement or method.

If the exception is not handled, it will "bubble" up to the `main` level and cause the app to terminate (usually after a default handler prints a message, etc).

However, you can make your block of code a `try` clause (by placing `try` or `@try` or whatever ahead of the `{`), follow that clause with a `catch` clause, and then, when the exception occurs, control will be transferred to the start of the `catch` clause.

The `catch` clause can look at the exception object and decide what to do with it.  Implementations vary a little, but usually if the `catch` clause does nothing the exception will be ignored and execution will continue after the `try/catch` clauses.  If, on the other hand, the `catch` clause *cannot* "handle" the exception somehow (and hence the exception should *not* be ignored), the `catch` clause will execute a `throw` to rethrow the original exception, or a newly created one.

When an exception is not handled by a given `try/catch` range, it is "bubbled up" to the next outer `try/catch`, in that method or its caller.  Eventually an unhandled exception reaches `main` and a default handler gets control.

`finally` is a feature of most exception handling models, not a critical function, but very convenient.  If a `try/catch` range is executed without generating an exception, the `finally` clause is executed and then execution continues after the `finally` clause.  On the other hand, if an exception is raised in the `try/catch` range and is not handled, the `finally` clause is executed and then the exception is "bubbled up", without executing the following code.

`finally` may be used, eg, to close an open file or release some allocated temporary resource.

Comment: And it should be noted that it's not unusual to see a `try/finally` combo, with no `catch`, where the intent is only to close/free some resource if an exception occurs.